# Product of sums of all subsets mod $k$?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, computational-complexity, products

Input: set of $N$ integers and $k$ value (modulo)

Output: product of sum of all subsets of input set (modulo $k$)

e.g. for input {1,2,3} and $k = 20$, we have 1 * 2 * 3 * (1+2) * (1+3) * (2+3) * (1+2+3) = 2160.

and:

$2160 \equiv 0 \pmod{20}$

Output is 0.

Could anyone suggest if you can implement such an algorithm optimally? (in polynomial time - if this is possible).

Comment: A particular case of you question is when $k$ is prime and we want only to determine whether the product is zero modulo $k$. This holds iff there exists a subset of the set whose sum is zero modulo $k$.  This reminds me  the classical [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is known to be [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness), so your problem may be NP-hard too. In this case there should be no polynomial time algorithm for it unless $P=NP$, that is $N=1$. :-)

Comment: An optimistic point of view is that who will propose a polynomial time algorithm for it [may be awarded by 1 000  000 $ bounty by Clay institute](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/p-vs-np-problem). :-D

Comment: If $N\ge k$, you can output $0$, bu the well-known application of the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution.  I'll edit later with the explanation.

---

Input: a set $S = \{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_N\}$, and an integer $k$.

Define matrices $P,Q$ of size $(N+1) \times k$ initializing the first row

$P_{0,i} = i$, $Q_{0,i} = 1$

and filling in successive rows by settting

$$P_{n,i} = P_{n-1,i} \cdot P_{n-1, i+s_n}$$
$$Q_{n,i} = P_{n-1,i} \cdot Q_{n-1, i+s_n} + P_{n-1,i} \cdot Q_{n-1, i+s_n}$$

while reducing everything (including indices) modulo $k$.

Output $Q_{N,0}$.

---

Filling in each entry of the matrix is just multiplication, addition, and reducing mod $k$, each of which I believe can be done in time $\log k$, so in total the algorithm is of order $Nk\log k$.

I implemented this in Python:

```
def aur(S, k):
    P = [list(range(k))]
    Q = [[1]*k]
    for n in range(1,len(S)+1):
        P.append([])
        Q.append([])
        for i in range(k):
            P[n].append( (P[n-1][i] * P[n-1][(i+S[n-1]) % k]) % k   )
            Q[n].append(  ( P[n-1][i] * Q[n-1][i] + Q[n-1][i]* P[n-1][(i+S[n-1]) % k]  ) % k )
    return Q[n][0]
```

You can check that e.g., aur$([1,2,3], 20) = 0$ and aur$([1,2,3], 3000) = 2160$ as in the OP's examples.

Edit:  Here is the explanation.

Define a polynomial $$P_S(x) = \prod_{T \subseteq S} (x + \sum_{i \in T} i).$$  If we set $x=0$, we almost get what we want, except that the product also includes the empty set which (I'm assuming) should not be there.  Nevertheless, it will be convenient to include it.  From $P_S(x)$ we can still recover our answer: we first divide by $x$ to eliminate the empty set, and then set $x=0$.  Equivalently, we take $P'(0)$.

The reason we define this polynomial is because it obeys a nice recurrence relation.  If we set $S_n = \{s_1, \ldots, s_n\}$, then

$$P_{S_n}(x) = P_{S_{n-1}}(x) P_{S_{n-1}}(x+s_n).$$

This follows from the fact that a subset $T$ of $S_n$ is either a subset $T$ of $S_{n-1}$, or a union $T \cup \{s_n\}$ for $T \subseteq S_{n-1}$.  Furthermore, we can start with the initial condition $P_{\emptyset}(x) = x$.

Computing the coefficients of $P_{S}(x)$ this way is enough to compute our output, but this polynomial will have degree $2^N$, so this is not feasible.  Instead, we use the product rule, setting $Q_S(x) = P_S'(x).$  This gives

$$Q_{S_n}(x) = P_{S_{n-1}}(x) Q_{S_{n-1}}(x+s_n) + Q_{S_{n-1}}(x) P_{S_{n-1}}(x+s_n).$$

We can then output $Q_{S_N}(0)$ and reduce mod $k$.  In this way we don't need the full list of exponentially many coefficients of these polynomials, but we only need to evaluate them for $x = 0, 1, \ldots, k$.

Comment: Thank You very much! However, will this solution work also in the case of negative numbers? Can You adjust them somehow?

Comment: It should work fine with either positive or negative numbers in the set.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Cool. However, $k$ may still be exponential in the length of the input (it takes only $\log k$ bits to express $k$), so technically, this is not a polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen Yes, it is exponential in the binary length of $k$. So it is not polynomial-time in that sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt at a polynomial time solution: We can of course assume that the given integers $a_i$ are in the range $\{0,\ldots,k-1\}.$ Denote by $v_m$ the number of times $m$ appears as a sum modulo $k$, i.e.

$$ v_m = |\{ S \subset [N] : \sum_{j \in S} a_j \equiv_k m\}| \leq 2^N,$$

for $m =0,\ldots,k-1$. The required sum is zero if $v_0 > 1$, otherwise it is

$$ \prod_{m=1}^{k-1} m^{v_m} \pmod k,$$
which can be computed with $\sum_{m=1}^{k-1} \log(v_m) \leq k N$ multiplications modulo $k$, so it is enough to compute $\{v_m\}$. Now consider the polynomial

$$ P(x) = \prod_{i=1}^N (1+x^{a_i}) = \sum_{S \subset [N]} x^{\sum_{j \in S} a_j}.$$
Then by taking $w_k = e^{-2 \pi i/ k}$, we can compute
$$ X_\ell = P(w_k^\ell) = \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} v_m w_k^{\ell m}.$$

$\{X_\ell\}$ is the discrete Fourier transform of $\{v_m\}$ so we just need to compute the inverse.

Comment: I do not believe you can make that assumption, because if $n$ and $n+k$ are both in the set, you have repetition.

Comment: I don't think I need the $a_i$ to be distinct.

Comment: This is nice!  I wonder if it is faster than my solution.

Comment: Thanks! I think they match, at least the way I wrote it. The bottleneck is doing the multiplication of the $m^{v_m}$'s, and you have to do $kN$ of them, so that takes $kN \log(k)$. I think it is more space efficient though: We just need to compute $O(k)$ numbers, instead of $Nk$.

Comment: @funda I have a question. Is it possible, thanks to your solution, to check (only) whether the given value modulo $k$ is $0$? I search very fast solution.

Comment: Well, at first you would think that you only need to compute $v_0$, but even if $v_0 =1$, the product might be zero, so you still need to compute the whole thing.